# React JS Higher-Order-Component not execute function if state is being set outside that function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, higher-order-components

I can't think about a proper sentence for the question title, so first I would like to apologize if the title is somehow confusing.

So I was just finish learning React JS and trying to build an app for practice. In this app there is a login form that if the email or password entered is wrong, it will show an alert and blank the fields.

With the basic React JS implementation all is well, but when I tried to modify my code to implement higher-order-component, the app become buggy and I can't seem to find where the culprit is.

So the buggy thing is, **if I enter the email or the password incorrectly**, and click login, than the fields will be blanked for me to input / try again, but It seems **the fields wont accept any input**, it just **stays blank** no matter what keys I pressed on keyboard, so that I need to refresh page so that the fields can accept my input again.

Here Are My Code:

```
function ResponseAlert(props){
    if(props.alertStatus!==undefined && props.alertStatus!==null){
        const className = 'alert alert-' + props.alertStatus;
        return <div className={className}>{props.alertMessage}</div>
    }

    return <div></div>;
}
function H2Title(props) {
    return <h2>{props.title}</h2>;
}
class InputText extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(evt){
        this.props.onInputChange(evt.target.id, evt.target.value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor={this.props.elemId}>{this.props.label}</label>
                    <input type={this.props.type} className="form-control" name={this.props.elemId} id={this.props.elemId} value={this.props.elemValue} onChange={this.handleChange} required={this.props.required} />
                </div>
            );
    }
}

function withSetStateFormData(WrappedComponents, componentName){
    return class extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { formdata: { email: '', password: '' } };
            this.setStateFormData = this.setStateFormData.bind(this);
        }
        setStateFormData(field, value){
            this.setState(function(state, props){
                let tempData = state.formdata;
                tempData[field] = value;
                return {
                    formdata: tempData
                };
            });
        }
        render(){
            return <WrappedComponents handleInputChange={this.setStateFormData} {...this.props} {...this.state} />
        }
    }
}

class FormLogin extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    alertstatus: null,
                    alertmessage: '',
                    formdata: this.props.formdata
                };
                this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            }  
            handleSubmit(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();

                const self = this;
                fetch("http://someurl.com/login.php",
                    {
                       mode: 'cors',
                       method: 'POST',
                       headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                       },
                       body: JSON.stringify(this.state.formdata)
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            response.json().then(function (resData) {
                                alert('Yeay! Successful login.');
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            //here is where the problem lies, I think.
                            self.setState({
                                alertstatus: 'danger',
                                alertmessage: 'Login failed. Email or password is incorrect.',
                                formdata: { email: '', password: '' }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });

                return false;
            }
            render(){
                const handleInputChange = this.props.handleInputChange;
                return (
                    <div>
                        <ResponseAlert alertStatus={this.state.alertstatus} alertMessage={this.state.alertmessage} />
                        <H2Title title="Login"/>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <InputText type="email" elemId="email" label="Email Address" elemValue={this.state.formdata.email} onInputChange={handleInputChange} required={true}/>

                            <InputText type="password" elemId="password" label="Password" elemValue={this.state.formdata.password} onInputChange={handleInputChange} required={true}/>

                            <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  );
                }
}

const EnhancedComponent = withSetStateFormData(FormLogin, "login");
ReactDOM.render(<EnhancedComponent />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

So I think after the setState function executed to blank the email and password, the onChange event somehow refuse to work to update the fields on input change.

Anybody please enlighten me what causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to say that you don't need to use a higher order component here however, what you are trying to do can work.

There are a couple problems that I see.

First, you are setting the `InputText` `value` according to the `FormLogin` state. That's fine however, when the `InputText` changes, it calls `onInputChange` which is set to `setStateFormData` from the higher-oder component. The problem is that `setStateFormData` sets the state for the higher-order component, not the state for `FormLogin`. So the result is that the `FormLogin` state doesn't update which means the `value` for `InputText` doesn't update.

I know what you are thinking, "But the input does update before I click submit". Yes, and no.

This brings us to the second problem which has to do with JS references.

*From the React docs*

> `state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from `state` and `props`.

If we look at `setStateFormData` you are technically directly mutating `state` by first referencing an object within `state` with `let tempData = state.formdata;` then modifying the referenced object with `tempData[field] = value;`. This is a big no-no in React because it leads to all sorts of confusing bugs, like this one.

You can build the new state from the old state but you are only allowed to copy values, not references. We can fix this by re-writing `setStateFormData` as follows:

```
setStateFormData(field, value){
  this.setState(function(state, props){
    let newFormData = {
      email: state.formdata.email;
      password: state.formdate.password;
    };

    newFormData[field] = value;

    return {
      formdata: newFormData
    };
  });
}
```

Now, we are deep copying the `formdata` from the old state. Great, one bug down. If we test the application again, now we see that the input never updates, before or after submit. This is because of the first problem mentioned above.

Before, the `InputText` `value` appeared to be updating because the `FormLogin` state appeared to be updating however, `state.formdata` in `FormLogin` was just a reference to `state.formdata` in the higher-order component which was set in the constructor of `FormLogin` with `formdata: this.props.formdata`. This meant that when `setStateFormData` directly mutated the state of the higher-order component, it was also directly muting the state of `FormLogin`. This made it look like everything was working but it was really just because of the references. As soon as a reference is lost, the app broke. So, when did we lose a reference? As you guessed, when we call `setState` in `handleSubmit`.

```
self.setState({
  alertstatus: 'danger',
  alertmessage: 'Login failed. Email or password is incorrect.',
  formdata: { email: '', password: '' }
});
```

This assigned `state.formdata` in `FormLogin` to a new object, breaking the reference to `state.formdata` in the higher-order component.

Okay, so how to fix it. There are a few ways.

I would recommend removing `formdata` from the state of `FormLogin` completely. That way you don't need to worry about keeping the two `formdata` objects in sync. Simply create a `clearFormData` function on the higher-order component and pass it down to `FormLogin` to call in `handleSubmit`. Additionally, you need to set the `TextInput` `value` according to the props of `FormLogin`. I think this is the cleanest solution while still using the higher-order component.

The simplest solution, is of course just getting rid of the higher-order component but I'm not sure if that is an option if your goal is specifically to learn about higher-order components.

Lastly, you could implement a [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) function on `FormLogin` which would rebuild the `FormLogin` state every time its props change which coincidentally happens every time the higher-order state changes. This is a clean way to update the `formdata` in `FormLogin` everything time it changes in the higher-order component. The problem is you still need to worry about updating the `formdata` in the higher-order component every time it changes in `FormLogin`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow a very good and comprehensive explanation. Your answer not only solve my problems, but also gives me more understanding about how react behave. Yes as you guess, Your 2nd solution of not using HOC is not an option because it defeats the purpose of the practice, an besides I will be using the setStateFormData for other component like FormSignUp, FormUpdateAccount, etc. So I need this HOC. I prefer Your 1st solution because it's more simpler and easier to understand for a learning beginner like me, and of course I've tried that 1st solution and it works like a charm. Thank You So Much.